# Why $(this).focus(); will not work on the same element when focusout in jquery

Tags: jquery

Initially i was trying to validate a user input when i stumbled with a problem is that i cant fix the cursor of the focus on an element when focusing out. this is the code

```
$("#ChapterCode").keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==9 || e.keyCode==13){
        if($(this).val()!=""){
            ChapterCode();
            get_fees();
            return true;
        }else{
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

this will work as return false will prohibit the focus from changing when clicking a TAB.
however

```
$("#ChapterCode").focusout(function(e){
        if($(this).val()!=""){
            ChapterCode();
            get_fees();
            return true;
        }else{
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

this wont work same as for blur any help ? i added e.preventDefault(); knowing that it wont work just in case. Help is really appreciated thanks again.
Please dont tell me to create an error message or something like that coz its simply out of the question.

Comment: I think this is an event execution order issue, focusout() run its code just before your input is losing focus.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like different browser behavior there.

In `Chrome` it works just like that. You can set the focus within the `blur` or `focusout`.

`FireFox` does not this. You need to wrap it into a `setTimeout()`.

```
$("#ChapterCode").focusout(function(e){
    if($(this).val()!=""){
        ChapterCode();
        get_fees();
        return true;
    }else{
        var self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
          self.focus();
        }, 1);            
        return false;
    }
});
```

This will setback the focus to `#ChapterCode`. You cannot completly prevent the box from losing the focus. You need to introduce a variable that holds the `this` reference, which can be accessed via closure from `setTimeout()`.

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/hGjwZ/1/

Comment: hmm interesting idea ill check it out and get back to you thanks :)

Comment: Man your are Guinness it worked with IE Firefox and Chrome thanks :D

Comment: @Mhammad: welcome, if you think this answer is helpful, you might want to "accept" it, marking it as correct.