# On focusout, focus

Tags: jquery

Does jQuery prevent this type of behavior?

```
$("input").focusout(function() {
    $(this).focus();
});
```

Comment: Browsers prevent behavior like this.  It isn't jQuery's fault.  It is a security feature.

Comment: @Lime: A very questionable security feature, if Šime Vidas's answer stands.

Comment: The correct event-type pairs are focusin/focusout, and focus/blur. Don't mix them...

Comment: @Jon Well if not a Security Feature, then it does prevent incompetent coders from seriously messing things up  :)  I can only imagine how frustrating things could be..... click what? click what? click what?!?? I'm done with that input computer!!

Comment: Did you attempt searching?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564481/why-this-focus-will-not-work-on-the-same-element-when-focusout-in-jquery

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how it's done (works cross-browser):

```
$('input').blur(function() {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() { $(that).focus(); }, 0);
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/jzt2Z/1/

Comment: @Dmitriy With great power comes great responsibility `:)`

Comment: Yeah focus one textbox then another and then another and it dances :}

Comment: @Dmitriy @Lime Check this out (try to type something): http://jsfiddle.net/jzt2Z/6/show/ `:)`

Answer (score 1):

1) Actually it works in Chrome. Here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/8WP53/

Once 1st input gets **focuseout** - it remains focused, and user cannot focus any other input

2) in IE I get an error "Stack overflow" (**brand name StackOverflow.com error :)** )

3) Strange, but in Firefox you can select any input, but no error is being produced